# .NET nanoFramework and System.IO.FileSystem on ESP-S2-WROVER

Tags: nanoframework

i have a esp32-s2-saola-1 with the ESP32-S2-WROVER chip. On these is KALUGA_1 flashed. It was the only build was works. Network and so on works. when I wants to use the System.IO.FileSystem, I become an Error see below. What's the reasion? On whitch processors is the System.IO.FileSystem usable? The Internal Memory (Drive I:) is on an ESP32 usable?

2>------ Bereitstellung gestartet: Projekt: AppStorage, Konfiguration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>Getting things ready to deploy assemblies to .NET nanoFramework device: KALUGA_1 @ COM3.
2>Deploy failed.
2>
2>***************************************************************************
2>
2>
2>The connected target does not have support for the following assembly(ies):
2>
2>    'System.IO.FileSystem'
2>
2>Please check:
2>  1) if the target is running the most updated image.
2>  2) if the target image was built to include support for all referenced assemblies.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is because the build for that target doesn't have support for System.IO.FileSystem.

Issue raised in the project GitHub. Please track for progress:
https://github.com/nanoframework/Home/issues/1145